# Unable to understand this JSON parse error

Tags: javascript, json

JSON parse error while paring the JSON string

I have this below JS code and it is giving error. I would like to print the engineCode and value?

Thanks.

```
//I have update the code. Sorry about the confusion ...
let a = '{ "car": "Honda", "specs": {"engineCode": 1001} }';
let b = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(b); //prints json
//JSON.parse(b.engineCode); //please ignore this .....
JSON.parse(b.specs); //error while parsing and how to fix??

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at bajahisowi.js:7:6
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:10866"
```

Comment: theres a `specs` property in the way.

Comment: `console.log(b.specs.engineCode)` instead of `JSON.parse(b.engineCode)`

Comment: JSON.parse is used to parse json strings as json object in javascript, but b.engineCode is already parsed

Comment: Once you've parsed it into an object, you don't need to parse it again.  The *entire structure* has been turned into an object.

Comment: The `JSON` is already parsed, you only need to parse it once, then access the properties as you do with a `Javascript` object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse again, just use it using dot notation

```js
let a = '{ "car": "Honda", "specs": {"engineCode": 1001} }';
let b = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(b.specs.engineCode); //prints json
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, **there is no need to re-parse it**. Try `console.log(b.specs.engineCode)` considering your JSON looks like:

```
{
  "car": "Honda",
  "specs": {
    "engineCode": 1001
  }
}
```

If you want *really* want to `b.engineCode` then refactor your JSON to reflect the following:

```
{
  "car": "Honda",
  "engineCode": 1001
}
```

Comment: No, the OP does *not* need to `JSON.parse(b.specs.engineCode)`.  The JSON is already parsed into an object.

Comment: @Amy Oh you are right, he can just `console.log` it.